# Why doesn't event bubbling work as expected when calling preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with one column being a formatted column that renders an `anchor` tag. The click handler associated with the anchor tag calls `preventDefault()`.

I also have a `onCellSelect` event handler registered with the grid that does something meaningful when the user clicks anywhere in the column where the `anchor` tag is rendered.

What I want to do is to show the `anchor` tag but when clicked it should fire the underlying `onCellSelect` handler registered with the grid.

However this does not work.

See an example jsFiddle located [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shardul/tcuwC/)

I have a jsFiddle located [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shardul/MNLru/) that does fire the bubbled event.

Not sure whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger another event when clicking another you can use the trigger function

```
$('.anchorClass').live('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     // get the current cell
     var $cell = $(e.target).parent('div');

     $($cell).trigger('onCellSelect');

});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MNLru/1/) how you can trigger one event from another

Comment: Thanks @CR41G14! This indeed fixed the issue for me, though I tend to agree with @Kevin that it is a bit hacky. In any case it does not answer my original question: Why doesn't the click event bubble up to its parent?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a hack, but it works:

```
$("#grid").delegate(".logDetailsDialogClass",'click', 
   function(e) {
      alert('link clicked');
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().trigger("click");
   });
```

note, you can continue to use `.live`, but i suggest against it. All i added was `$(this).parent().trigger("click");`

Comment: Why do you suggest against using .live? It would be really helpful if you could explain the reasons behind it.

Comment: @ShardulKulkarni .live is Very inefficient, it first tries to select all elements that match the selector, then it doesn't do anything with them. Furthermore, it binds the event to the document which means the event has to bubble all the way to the document before it can be handled. If you use .delegate (or .on in 1.7+) in the way i did above, it doesn't needlessly select elements and it binds to an element closer to the target element so that the event doesn't have to bubble so far.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing a couple of things here (you should just read the jQuery documentation)

`event.preventDefault()`: If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.
`event.stopPropagation()`: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.
`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`: Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

And also, you should read the Additional notes on `.stopPropagation()` and `.stopImmediatePropagation()`:

### Additional Notes:

- Since the `.live()` method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events. Similarly, events handled by `.delegate()` will propagate to the elements to which they are delegated; event handlers bound on any elements below it in the DOM tree will already have been executed by the time the delegated event handler is called. These handlers, therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by calling `event.stopPropagation()` or returning `false`.

Comment: As far as I know `preventDefault` does not prevent the event from bubbling. All it prevents from happening is carrying out the default action. In case of the `<a>` tag it will not navigate the browser to the specified `href`. What is perplexing though is the fact that the click event in this specific case does not bubble up. Anyone know why?

Comment: @ShardulKulkarni What specific case are you talking about? The mentioned methods work just as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/gQDxm/

Comment: The specific case where an `anchor` tag click event does not bubble up to the jqGrid object in which it is rendered. Did you get a chance to check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shardul/tcuwC/) mentioned in the question?

Comment: @ShardulKulkarni In that case, the event does bubble up to the document (you are binding the handler with `.live()`, read the Additional Notes in my answer). I modified your example so you can see what happens when `e.preventDefault()` is removed. It's still not executing "onCellSelect" (see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcuwC/6/), try dblclick). You should read the documentation or source code of jqGrid to see what happens in setGridParam, and how is it calling handlers in each case, but for sure `e.preventDefault()` is not the reason "onCellSelect" does not get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest, removing the `anchors` and replacing them with `spans`? If you really need them to link somewhere you can use a mix of CSS and Jquery to simulate `anchor` actions.

Comment: I would like to use the styles created for `<a>` tags. Creating specific `CSS` styles to make `<span>`'s look like `<a>`'s seems a bit of an overkill.

Comment: @ShardulKulkarni I'd rather go with overkill than banging my head on a wall trying to figure out a work around or rewriting a plugin.